# Not receiving the JSON object on onClick

Tags: jquery, json, node.js, ajax, ejs

I have very small UseCase. The user enters the ISBN of a book and is shown a book with that particular ISBN. However, only half of the functionality is working.

For some reason, I am not able to receive the JSON containing the book in the `ejs` so I can populate the table with only one book.

Here I am calling the search function and then i populate the table with the book

```
function searchISBN() {
        var input = $('#IdSearchISBN').val();
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.get('/searchISBN/' + input, function (data, status) {
                var trJSON = '';
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    trJSON += '<tbody><tr><td>' +
                        data[i].ISBN +
                        '</td><td>' +
                        data[i].BookTitle +
                        '</td><td>' +
                        data[i].BookAuthors +
                        '</td><td>'
                        + data[i].Publisher +
                        '</td><td>' +
                        data[i].Description +
                        '</td><td>' +
                        data[i].CallNumber +
                        '</td></tr></tbody>';
                });
                $('#booksTable').append(trJSON);
            });
        });
    }
```

This is the function that does the searching and returns backs the book

```
app.get('/searchISBN/:searchID', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.params.searchID);
    if (req.params.searchID != "" && req.params.searchID) {
        BookTable.find({ISBN: req.params.searchID}, function (err, booksList) {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500);
                return console.error(err);
            }
            console.log("I have sent data");
            console.log(booksList);
            res.send(booksList);
        });
    }
});
```

I did put logs to see if the search function was really sending the book or not and yes it does. However, I am not able to receive it
Below are the logs I got.

`9780730324218
I have sent data
[ { _id: 58c7d0694172ab199c6de78e,
    ISBN: '9780730324218',
    BookTitle: 'The Barefoot Investor : The Only Money Guide You\'ll Ever Need',
    BookAuthors: 'Scott Pape',
    Publisher: 'John Wiley & Sons Australia Ltd',
    Description: 'This is the only money guide you\'ll ever need That\'s a bold claim, given there are already thousands of finance books on the shelves.',
    CallNumber: ' 0730324214',
    __v: 0 } ]`

Any suggestions?

Comment: put a console.log(data) after $.get('/searchISBN/' + input, function (data, status) { and see what you get.
And remove the $(document).ready(function () { 
You don't need that. That just executes code when the dom is ready and you're calling it inside a function which isn't necessary.

Comment: @Taintedmedialtd I made the recommended changes. However, console.log(data) doesn't give show anything

Comment: Tough one. The GET request doesn't return anything in the browser console? Not even an error?

Comment: nope nothing. I even tried `alert`.

Comment: I've refactored the frontend code in an answer below. See if it helps:

Answer (score 0):

Your returned data is not valid JSON, as the `_id` property is a string but it's not quoted correctly. Fix that and the code works:

```js
var data = [{
  _id: '58c7d0694172ab199c6de78e',
  ISBN: '9780730324218',
  BookTitle: 'The Barefoot Investor : The Only Money Guide You\'ll Ever Need',
  BookAuthors: 'Scott Pape',
  Publisher: 'John Wiley & Sons Australia Ltd',
  Description: 'This is the only money guide you\'ll ever need That\'s a bold claim, given there are already thousands of finance books on the shelves.',
  CallNumber: ' 0730324214',
  __v: 0
}]

var trJSON = '';
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
  trJSON += '<tbody><tr><td>' +
    data[i].ISBN +
    '</td><td>' +
    data[i].BookTitle +
    '</td><td>' +
    data[i].BookAuthors +
    '</td><td>' + data[i].Publisher +
    '</td><td>' +
    data[i].Description +
    '</td><td>' +
    data[i].CallNumber +
    '</td></tr></tbody>';
});
$('#booksTable').append(trJSON);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="booksTable"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's an issue with the frontend JS and the $(document).ready() being part of the function:

```
function searchISBN() {
    $.get('/searchISBN/' + $('#IdSearchISBN').val())
    .done(function(data){
        var trJSON = '';
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            trJSON += '<tbody><tr><td>';
            trJSON += [data[i].ISBN,data[i].BookTitle,data[i].BookAuthors,data[i].Publisher,data[i].Description,data[i].CallNumber].join('</td><td>');
            trJSON += '</td></tr></tbody>';
        });
        $('#booksTable').append(trJSON);
    })
    .fail(function(){
        console.log("Error");
    });
};
```

That's returning "error" so the GET request is failing. I think, like the other answer, that the ObjectID is upsetting your browser. Update this in the app and it should work now:

```
app.get('/searchISBN/:searchID', function (req, res) {
    if (req.params.searchID != "" && req.params.searchID) {
        BookTable.find({ISBN: req.params.searchID}, function (err, booksList) {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500);
                return console.error(err);
            }
            var response = [];
            booksList.forEach(function(book) {
                var _book = book.toObject;
                delete _book._id;
                response.push(_book);
            })
            res.send(response);
        });
    }
});
```